# Parse Yaml with sentence or multiple words

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yaml file -

```yaml
groups:
  - name: Group 1 for Application 1
  - name: Group 2 for Application 2
```

I need to parse this yaml, and store it in a variable so that I can iterate.

If I just do

```bash
group_names=($(yq eval '.groups[].name' test.yaml))
for name in "${group_names[@]}"; do
    echo $name
done
```

It prints

```
Group
1
for
Application
1
Group
2
for
Application
2
```

I also tried

```bash
group_names=($(yq eval '.groups[].name | join(",")' test.yaml))
Error: cannot join with !!str, can only join arrays of scalars
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store every `.name` value from the YAML array `.groups` into an indexed Bash array `group_names`, use Bash's `declare -a` to define an array, and yq's `@sh` to escape the values for shell. Wrap the declaration in parentheses to make it an array, and use double quotes in Bash to print values that contain whitespace characters.

```bash
unset group_names
declare -a group_names="($(yq eval '.groups[].name | @sh' test.yaml))"

for name in "${group_names[@]}"; do echo "Next name: $name"; done
```

```
Next name: Group 1 for Application 1
Next name: Group 2 for Application 2
```

Tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.35.1 (Note: since version 4.18.1, the `eval` command can be omitted)

For [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/), replace `yq eval` with `yq -r`.